# when loading a model in tensorflow.js for node, the weights aren't loaded/saved

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js

When I load a trained model (In tensorflow.js within Node.js) that I have previously saved, the model topology is being loaded, but none of the weights are loaded (so I have to train the model from scratch). No errors are thrown.

To save the model, I am using:

```
async function save(path) {
    //misc. unrelated code goes here
    await model.save('file://' + path);
}
```

All files appear (`model.json` and `weights.bin`), and no errors are thrown.

To load the file, I am using :

```
async function load(path) {
    //misc. unrelated code goes here.
    model = await tf.loadLayersModel('file://' + path + '/model.json');
}
```

Again, no errors are thrown. The model topology is loaded correctly. The weights aren't though, and the model behaves as if I had just constructed/compiled it.

I am using tfjs-node save:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
require("tfjs-node-save");
```

I would really appreciate any help or advice!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this was just a dumb mistake.

I had a wrapper function to add some functionality to `model.compile()`.

For some godforsaken reason, in that function, I called my initialization function, which overwrote the model.

tl;dr, don't overwrite a model you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

save() and loadLayersModel() are async functions.

`model.save(url).then(result => console.log(result));`

`tf.loadLayersModel(url).then(result => console.log(result))`

Comment: Thank you for your response! I already have these calls in async functions. I'm not sure why I thought that was irrelevant. Probably because I'm new to javascript, and don't know any better 0.o.   I've updated the question. Ty again!